# Lumen JWT token send with request

Tags: php, laravel, token, jwt, lumen

I have successfully authenticated a user and can get authenticated user by providing the token in postman.

I wrote another endpoint which is in auth middleware:

```
$api->get('/categories', [
    'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\CategoryController@index',
    'as' => 'api.categories',
]);
```

The method it calling is :

```
public function index() {
    $lessons = \App\Category::all();
    return response()->json([
        'data' => $lessons,
        'code' => 200,
    ]);
}
```

When i call api/categories, It returns :

```
{
  "message": "Failed to authenticate because of bad credentials or an invalid authorization header.",
  "status_code": 401
}
```

**How can i provide the token with request ?**

Answer (score 0):

You can make the call with the token in query string or in the request header. Assuming your token is 12345, do this.

```
http://localhost:8000/categories?token=12345
```

With header

```
Key : Authorization
Value : Bearer 12345

http://localhost:8000/categories
```

Comment: Replace the text `12345` with the token.